# How to navigate from received meeting response to respective event in calendar?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003

The question is simple, but I can't figure it out and don't find mauch around with Google either:

When I receive a meeting response in my Inbox, how can I navigate from there to the respective meeting in my calendar?